# 480 VDC Series Battery Bank - Solar PV Charging Current Feedback Control Circuit

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, current-limiting

I have a 480VDC Lead Acid Battery Bank (40 x 12VDC 50Ahr Batteries in Series) directly coupled to a 5.0 Kilowatt Solar PV Array [with an output range of 560-580 VDC and maximum output of 8.9 Amps). This simple coupled circuit works well but I want to add a feedback activated control device that limits the Battery Bank Charging Current to precisely 3.0 Amps maximum as the Solar Irradiation and PV Array Output Current varies. I am not concerned with the minimum Charging Current just the 3.0 Amp maximum. Any circuit suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If the charge current is limited like you say which is a good idea what do you intend to do with the excess electricity?

Comment: In principle all you need is a constant current regulator. These can be constructed from a floating voltage regulator and a feedback resistor - see http://www.diy-audio-guide.com/constant-current-source.html - but you need careful design and specialist components at those voltages and powers

Comment: What output voltage will the solar bank rise to in full sunlight when supplying only 3 amps?

Comment: Autistic the solar array services a varying load.

Comment: Andy aka it will never exceed 600 volts

Comment: lcy thanks the reference seems to not be scalable to 3A at 600V

Comment: You can design a floating regulator that will never see the full 600V. It will only ever see the difference between array and bank voltage. However, if the bank is fully discharged, it could be 400V or less, so that is still probably not reasonable for a linear circuit.

Comment: A linear regulator that dissipates power is unlikely to be a good idea. And the battery is NOT a 480V battery. At fully float charged it is 13.8V x 40 = 550V (assuming flooded lead acid). If you do NOT return them to this voltage after loading they will die soonish. Occasoonally you must boost tem to about 14.4V x 40 = 575V and failure to do so will also shorten lifetime. | Commercial soar controllers that do the above properly are readily available and cost far less than the PV panels and batteries. Not using a controller that competently meets battery requirements is VERY false economy.

Comment: Thanks Russell that sounds like good advice. So which of the readily available commercial solar controllers that you refer to  [480 VDC battery string] do you recommend. I cant seem to find any?

Comment: @Lawrence I was suggesting an idea - not an actual solution. I *think* that the basic idea of creating a current source from a voltage regulator would work using a switch mode voltage regulator, instead of the linear regulator, obviously the components used in the regulator would need to be rated for the full solar panel voltage. Using a switch mode regulator would reduce the power dissipation from the hundreds of watts to just a few watts.

Comment: I have to admit, for solar charge controllers, the highest battery bank voltage I have seen is 48V. I have not ever seen one designed for 480V.

Comment: Maybe a PWM switcher on the low side of the solar array.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic shows two simple linear floating current regulators connected in parallel.

With guesses of what the voltage ranges that the circuit has to operate, the voltage differential can be 150V. So the power such a linear regulator has to dissipate would be up to 150V x 3A = 450W.

450W seem like a lot to waste, but the sun energy would have converted to heat outside if it were not collected anyway.

So now, how to have such a floating current regulator dissipates 450W. I think one way is to duplicate it as many times as necessary and connect them in parallel. For example, with 10 of them, each one is set up to pass 0.3A and may dissipate up to 45W.

On one of the regulator, there is a suggestion of how to connect a DC fan.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWhx4r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @rioaxe here is an alt design logically similar to yours for your comment please.  Sensing Cct - I visualize a precision [known] low value R in series with the batt bank [low batt side] such as a current shunt. From the known R [shunt R] and known I [3.0 A] - V Out [in millivolts] is calculated and used as a “trigger” that invokes a Control Cct attenuating the batt charging current by providing an alternative parallel current path. The 2 paths share the amps capability only when 3 A is resolved by the Sense Cct. At other current values [< 3 A] the control Cct remains off & draws no A.

Comment: The alternative parallel path would be around 480V, so potentially even more power dissipation is involved. Take what have been given at face values, the solar panel supplies up to 5000W. You want to limit the battery charging to around 1500W (3A x 500V) by shunting the extra power. When there is no other load, then the shunt has to consume up to 5000W - 1500W = 3500W.